# Reactor log with MDC context within map

Tags: slf4j, reactor, webflux

In my Spring Webflux application to have tracing headers in the logs (MDC) I have followed the FAQ from Reactor (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.mdc). It works nice. However, it is not suitable when I need to add logs with synchronous processing (like within map).

To solve this problem I have created a decorator for slf4j Logger which takes as a parameter the ContextView:

```java
public class LoggerWithMDC {
  private final Logger logger;

  public void info(String message, ContextView context, Object... args) {
    logWithTracingHeaders(context, () -> logger.info(message, args));
  }

  private static void logWithTracingHeaders(ContextView context, Runnable logStatement) {
    final Map<String, String> mdcTracingValues = extractTracingValuesFromContext(context);
    try {
      mdcTracingValues.forEach(MDC::put);
      logStatement.run();
    } finally {
      mdcTracingValues.keySet().forEach(MDC::remove);
    }
  }
}
```

and the sample usage:

```java
Mono.deferContextual(Mono::just)
    .flatMap(
        contextView ->
            Mono.just("value")
                .map(
                    value -> {
                      loggerWithMDC.info("Received value to convert: {}", contextView, value);
                      return value.toUpperCase();
                    })
                .contextWrite(Context.of("traceid", ULID.random())))
```

It works fine but is there any better way to do this without passing contextView?